# how to access angularjs in jsp in spring tool suit

Tags: angularjs

I am using Spring Tool suite

Where my directory Structure is :

```
MyAPP 
    ->src
       ->main
          ->webapp
             ->WEB-INF
                ->js
                  angular.js
                ->spring
                ->views
                   login.jsp
```

Now in login.jsp I have to access Angular.js but it is not Accessable

I am using

```
login.jsp
----------
<script src="/MyApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/js/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once compiled, assembled in a war and deployed to your web container (which your IDE is doing it for you), the root of the application is the webapp folder. Since a Java webapp is deployed under a context path, you need to prepend this context path to the URLs you use:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/js/angular.js" />
```

or, with the JSTL

```
<script src="<c:url value='/WEB-INF/js/angular.js'/>"></script>
```

But even that won't work, because everything under WEB-INF is inaccessible from the outside, by design. So you must put your JS files outside of WEB-INF.

This shows a serious lack of understanding of how Java webapps are, what's their structure, etc. You should familiarize with these basic things before going further.